# React Function vs Template re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have simple counter app

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as React from 'react';

const app = document.querySelector('#root');
let count = 0;

const increment = () => {
    count++;
    render();
}

var as = {};

const render = () => {
    var Component = () => (
        <div>
            <h2>Differ</h2>
            <h1>123{count}</h1>
            <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
            <div>3333</div>
        </div>
    );
    var template = (
        <div>
            <h2>Differ</h2>
            <h1>123{count}</h1>
            <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
            <div>3333</div>
        </div>
    );
    // If click on increment react re-render only the count "text" element 
    ReactDOM.render(
        template, app
    );
    // If click on increment react re-render the whole component
    // ReactDOM.render(
    //     <Component />, app
    // );
}




render();
```

if i use `ReactDOM.render(template, app)`. react re-render only the specific element.

if i use `ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, app)` react re-render whole app.

they are same components so why it act like this ? what the different between Component vs template ?

**If I declare Componenet example outside render function react render only the spesific element**

i check this with chrome dev-tools( rendering => paint flushing).

Answer (score -1):

Ideally *you* shouldn't be re-rendering the whole tree every time, anyways. You should be using ["internal" state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 }

  render() {
    const onClick = () => { this.setState(({ count }) => ({ count: count + 1 }))}
    return (
      <button>{this.state.count}</button>
    )
  }
}
```

The difference between `template` and `Component` is that `template` is a JSX/React Element, and `Component` is a React (Stateless/Functional)Component.

See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) for a little more info

React will also try to resolve and optimise the difference between two trees (old/new).

In the first example, `render(template, app)` - you're still using the same `template` element, so React will compare its children against the new children, and update only those whose props have changed. In the second example, you're passing in a new instance of `Component` (`<Component/>` is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement("Component")`), so React will completely replace that subtree.

[Here's some info](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) on how React reconciles between tree-states.

Comment: I think in that case, React considers the Component type to be the same, so it recurses into the Component's children. If you re-define `Component`, it considers the types different.